# Skip ThenBy on nullable objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a query which should be ordered like that:

```
var list = new List<MonthClosureViewModel>();
var orderedList = list
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Project)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.ChargeLine)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.DomesticSite) //<- x.DomesticSite might be null sometimes
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.ChargeSite)   //<- x.ChargeSite   might be null sometimes
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.RateGroup)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.ApprovedHrs)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.NotApprovedHrs);

public class MonthClosureViewModel
{
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public ChargeLine ChargeLine { get; set; }
    public Site DomesticSite { get; set; }
    public Site ChargeSite { get; set; }
    public RateGroup RateGroup { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public decimal ApprovedHrs { get; set; }
    public decimal NotApprovedHrs { get; set; }
}
```

But if any object is null (totally by design) this query fails.
How can I put null values at the end or skip ordering if object is null?

**ADDED:**
as @LasseV.Karlsen mentioned I might have ANOTHER problem.
I really got `ArgumentNullException`, but the reason was not behind some object were `null` (I saw it in debugger and falsely thought that it was my problem).
The real reason was as @RaphaëlAlthaus mentioned that I didn't implement `IComparable<>` at ANY of my classes in `MonthClosureViewModel`...

After I've done it everything start working as intended even if object is `null`

Comment: Can you tell us *how* it fails? Basically, what is the exception type, the exception message, and the stacktrace? `ThenByDescending` will not throw an exception if the result of calling that delegate is `null` so there has to be something else that fails.

Comment: Or does "fail" mean something completely different, like producing data sorted in the incorrect order?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it fails with `ArgumentNullException`. `ThenByDescending` throws it when `source` or `selector` is null [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534736(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The selector, yes, the source, yes, but neither of these are true here. The selector is the lambda, and we can see it in plain sight, that's not going to be null. The source is the collection, which comes from the previous call to `ThenByDescending`, which is also guaranteed not to be null. As such, *these are not relevant here*. Can you show us the stack trace?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think you might be right. I should investigate more on this

Comment: Do your complex ordering properties implement IComparable / IComparer ? No problem on that part ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus you were right. I've updated my post. If you add this as answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @Szer answered with some alternative solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to order by complex properties, which is (as you mentionned)  the real problem.

To make it possible you'll have to, either

1. implement `IComparable<T>` on your classes
2. use other overloads of OrderBy / OrderByDescending, which take also an `IComparer<TKey>` as argument ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb549422(v=vs.110).aspx) for the OrderBy overload)
3. Use a simple property of the complex property in your order by clause (with null check. In this case, the null check becomes necessary to avoid a Null Reference Exception) :

For example :

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Project == null ? string.Empty : x.Project.Name)
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to define `defaultSite` and `defaultChargeSite` to be either smaller or larger than all the other objects in their class

```
var list = new List<MonthClosureViewModel>();
var orderedList = list
     .Where(x => x != null);
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Project)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.ChargeLine)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.DomesticSite==null?defaultSite:x.DomesticSite) //<- x.DomesticSite might be null sometimes
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.ChargeSite==null?defaultChargeSite:x.ChargeSite)   //<- x.ChargeSite   might be null sometimes
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.RateGroup)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.ApprovedHrs)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.NotApprovedHrs);
```

Comment: probably `x => x.DomesticSite ?? defaultSite` will do the same. I'll try it

Comment: I think the incorrect assumption here is that `ThenByDescending` will not be able to handle `null`, but it does, it does not throw an exception if it encounters `null`. As such, *that is not a problem we need to handle*. The problem thus has to be elsewhere.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you were right. I've updated my post